# Generics error in java

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, collections

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> doub = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(5);
        arr.add(6);
        arr.add(7);
        doub.add(6.5);
        doub.add(8.5);
        doub.add(7.5);
        calc_test(arr);
        calc_test(doub);

public static void calc_test(List<Number> list) {
        for (Number obj : list) {
            System.out.println(obj + "");
        }
    }
```

I know this is an error in java and can be corrected by adding `? extends Number` in the function parameter, but why does the normal way not work? After all double and integer are a type of number and a list of those types should still be a type of number, so why is that an error?

Comment: Edit into your question the details of the error.

Answer (score 1):

`Double` and `Integer` is subclass of `Number` but `ArrayList<Double>` and `ArrayList<Integer>` are not subclass  of `ArrayList<Number>`. 
For more detail [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: I have read the java docs and i needed a simpler explanation as to why such a thing was not possible.